# Simple OOP system in R / binary operator overloading

Tags: r, oop

I'm exploring R's capabilities and trying to build a very simple object oriented programming system.

The idea is to use function environments to store object attributes, and to overload the ">" operator as a replacement for the "." typically used in OOP languages. This is implemented below.

```
`>.object` <- function (this, variable) {
  return(eval(substitute(variable), environment(this)))
}

new <- function (obj) {
  structure(unclass(obj), class="object")
}
```

For instance, I can create a `Dog` class with a `bark`method as follows.

```
Dog <- function () {

  bark <- function() {
    print("Woof!")
  }

  return(new(function(){}))
}

max = Dog()
`>.object`(max, bark()) # Prints "Woof!"
```

However, when using the operator `>` inline, R trys to resolve `bark()` in the global environment, yielding an error if it has not been defined.

```
max>bark() # Error in bark() : could not find function "bark"
```

If `bark` is somehow defined in the global environment, then there's no error.

```
bark = function(){}
max>bark() # Prints "Woof!"
```

Is there any way to work around this behaviour, so that `max>bark()` always returns "Woof!"?

Answer (score 0):

The `>.object` syntax is for generic functions (e.g., `mean`, `print`, `summary`). These are defined with `UseMethod()`:

```
> mean 
function (x, ...) 
UseMethod("mean")
<bytecode: 0x0000000017fc9f10>
<environment: namespace:base>
```

`>` is not a generic function:

```
> `>`
function (e1, e2)  .Primitive(">")
```

However, it can be redefined as a generic function:

```r
`>` <- function (x, ...) {
   UseMethod(">", x)
}
```

After doing this, running the code from the question produces the output `"Woof!"` as desired.

The disadvantage is that you now have to redefine `>` for the basic data types, e.g.:

```r
`>.double` <- function(x, y) !(x <= y)
```